# ngx-emoji-mart error Property '"x"' is incompatible with index signature

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-emoji-mart

I've installed in my 15.2.8 angular app the library **ngx-emoji-mart** from https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/emoji-mart

I've imported it in the module

```
import { PickerModule } from '@ctrl/ngx-emoji-mart';

imports: [
...
PickerModule,
...
```

]

Added it in the component  `<emoji-mart set="apple" class="emoji-mart"></emoji-mart>`
And imported the style in the styles.css `@import '@ctrl/ngx-emoji-mart/picker';

The problem is that when I serve it, it gives me a list of error:

```
Property '"categories"' is incompatible with index signature.
Type '{ alias: "categories"; required: false; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Property '"emojis"' is incompatible with index signature.
Type '{ alias: "emojis"; required: false; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Property '"skin"' is incompatible with index signature.
Type '{ alias: "skin"; required: false; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

And so on.

Do you know why it happens and how to fix it?
Thank you

Comment: What is the version of @ctrl/ngx-emoji-mart library? Have you tried update to Angular v16?

Comment: I couldn't update the version because of some dependencies. So I changed library and opted for Quill.js.. even though now i have problems with installing the emoji plugin. *facepalm*

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<emoji-mart (emojiClick)="addEmoji($event)"></emoji-mart>
```

ts:

```
public addEmoji(event:any){
console.log(event);
}
```

in the module file:

```
import { PickerComponent } from '@ctrl/ngx-emoji-mart';

@NgModule({
   imports: [
   ...,
   PickerComponent,
   ]
})
```